# How to run a python function on every Admin page load in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-admin

I would like a python function to be run any time a page from the admin interface is loaded.  This does not need to run on every page load(ie non-admin related pages).  This function requires the request object or the user id.

I know I could create a new view and call it from javascript from the page, but this seems like a horrible way of doing it.  Is there a way to somehow attach a function to admin page loads server side without adding any additional dependencies?

Update: the function is used to hook into a kind of logging system that keeps track of first/last interaction of each user each day that needs to be updated whenever the user uses the admin interface.  It would seem that a middleware app would allow me to do what I want to do, thank you guys!

Comment: What sort of "Python function" are you talking about? What does it do? The best solution will depend on the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Disclaimer:* I don't know a terrible lot about the internals or API(s) of Django perse.

What you need to use/write is a Middleware Component.

See: [Django Middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/)

**Trivial Example:**

class LocaleMiddleware(object):

```
def process_request(self, request):

    if 'locale' in request.cookies:
        request.locale = request.cookies.locale
    else:
        request.locale = None

def process_response(self, request, response):

    if getattr(request, 'locale', False):
        response.cookies['locale'] = request.locale
```

See also: [Understanding Django Middleware](http://effectivedjango.com/middleware.html) from Effective Django.

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to create a middleware and check on every page request if it is an admin page:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/

Answer (score 0):

I would deal it with a simple way. Find a function the admin must execute such as `save_model()`. Then put your own function in it.

Comment: That's terrible way of doing this. Hacks are just that "Hacks".

Comment: This works for events that only trigger on save of objects, but I need it to run on page load even when no saves are performed.  I actually use this method for saving what user last edited or what user created certain objects.

Comment: Yes, it has limitations.